# Different shaped divs

Tags: html, css, shapes

I need to create two divs like in image. both can have background images. Any one can help?

[Two divs http://development.230i.com/tsips_new/v2/images/Untitled.png](http://development.230i.com/tsips_new/v2/images/Untitled.png)

Comment: You could take a look at css clipping/masking: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: Atleast show us what u tried.

Comment: reckon a picture is worth a thousand words here, no need for a bunch of broken code and a detailed explanation

Comment: @ToniLeigh - Usually the Asker should be showing their attempt and they should *always* show some kind of research effort. This is *especially* important for new users to learn so they can make positive contributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

**Old School**

One way would be to crop the overlaid image so that it has a triangle cut off and replaced by transparency. This would work in any browser that supported .pngs, however, the downside would be that for each image you'd need to create a new crop. A photo-shop batch process or server side image processing job on upload would cover this best, depending on whether you have full control over the images (photoshop) or are dealing with user uploaded images (server side processing)

**Masking**

By using css masks you could create a mask for the overlaying div that forced transparency through the overlaying div to the div beneath it. You'd want an image where the triangle cut-out is black and the rest transparent. The black area is the area that is retained, while the rest of the div is transparent, revealing the div underneath.

This answer here gives [a working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30874621/1249829), though the shape is different.

The syntax is pretty simple, you just define a `-mask-image` with a url that works like a background image. Prefixes are required and support is still [a bit limited](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask).

**Clip Path**

Clip path allows you to clip the overlaying div to let a div underneath show through. You can use [this tool](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to set it up. I've nicked the following css from their output that defines a triangle on the bottom:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 38%, 42% 100%, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(100% 38%, 42% 100%, 100% 100%);
```

In this example, the overlaying div is clipped to the triangle shape allowing the white background to show through. Again, [support is limited](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path).

[More about clip-path and masking](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/).

**With all examples**

It's possible with all examples to swap the overlaying div to be the triangle or the square with a corner cut off. It makes no difference to the result.

Also, in all cases you'd need to use position to overlay the two divs on top of each other exactly. Like this:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I created this using one div and one image because I needed to add a hover effect. I created a fiddle here for that and I really appreciate your help.  [link-for-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjxyckz7/)